# Robustly standardize residuals in MM regression

Tags: regression, outliers, residuals, robust

Does anyone know how we can robustly standardize the residuals in MM regression?
First we perform MM regression and then obtain the residuals: how can we robustly standardize the residuals obtained from MM regression? I have found the method for least median squares (LMS) and least trimmed mean squares (LTS) in which the scale of the errors is estimated using a formula and then the residuals will be divided by that estimated scale. But for MM regression I could not find a formula for estimating the scale of the errors in order to standardize the residuals.

Answer (score 1):

The robust scale is normally output by the routine you used to estimate the MM. 
For example, in R:

```
library(robustbase)
data(coleman)
set.seed(0)
RlmST <- lmrob(log.light ~ log.Te, data = starsCYG)
RlmST$scale
```

There is no explicit formula to compute it: it's the result 
of an iterative scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. you are right that its the result if iterative scheme. what I am going to do is to labele the outliers using the standardized resiudals obtained from MM regression.
I think if I standardize the residuals as "residuals/sd(residuals)" and then check for large values to be labeled as outliers, this way cant be a good way . And even using RlmST$scale and
standardizing as residuals/

Comment: I want to robustly standardize the
residuals obtained using MM regression.
For example for LTS(Robust statistics for outlier detection, Rousseeuw et al.), the standardized LTS residuals
are obtained by residual/S where S^2=c^2*sum((r_(i))^2)/h..r(i) are ordered residuals. Now y question is that how I can robustly standardize the residuals obtained by using MM regression

Comment: Yes, but only using the "scale" component returned by the MM routine you use. Using the usual s.d. defeats the whole purpose of robust estimation, since it is itself liable to being swindled by the outliers. Also, the whole point of MM estimation was to dispose with outlier identification in the first place. If you're out to identify outliers, you might prefer an estimation approach based on 1-0 weights (like the FLTS).

Comment: I want to use an estimation approach like what you said based on 1-0 weights. Also I tried what you said to standardize the residuals using the scale obtained from MM regression as Sres=res/scale. And then compared the values of the AbsSR=abs(Sres) with 2.5 to weigh the observations. but the results was strange and the values for AbsSR were really large.

Comment: 'for AbsSR were really large' that's okay: it just mean you have large outliers. Presumably, the MM coefficients will be very different from the usual OLS ones. "I want to use an estimation approach like what you said based on 1-0 weights" then use FastLTS.

Comment: since MM regression has high breakdown point and high efficiency, I wanted to use MM regression and then find a way for robustly standardizing the residuals and check the outliers.

Comment: If I use LTS, what is the value for the fixed constant c to obtain the scale of the errors?

Comment: The whole efficiency of MM comes from the fact that it doesn't hard exclude any observations, merely pulls them in the direction of the main fit. The constant $c$ should be computed by the routine you use (the scale component returned by the LTS fit should return an estimate of scale already adjusted for $c$, in the absence of further info about what implementation you are using it's impossible to be more precise). $c$ is about 1.48.

Comment: I also check with LTS and standardizing the residuals. still I find large values. thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Well, then it means you have outliers....